# How to add button and database connectivity in rectjs

Tags: reactjs, database, button, store, family-tree

I am creating a family tree using Reactjs and i am build a familytree and the problem is how too add buttons in round circle and image is store displayed in round circle and that image stores in database

add buttons in round circle and image is store displayed in round circle and that image stores in database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What library do you use to create the family tree?